# How many old indices I should have for ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

I am using ElasticSearch with mainly default configuration and noticed recently that my old indices are eating too much space. I believe they are being created automatically because of default configuration since I have not done any such configuration. Please help me with:

- how many old indices I should generally keep?
- does my today's search use index created yesterday?
- can i live with just one index copy and reuse the same every time?
- what purpose old indices serve?

Since ES is running on a Production server, I simply cannot delete old indices hence need expert advice. Thanks.

Comment: Curious why you're building new indices all the time? The more common case is to just have one index in the same way you'd have one database in a SQL db. Then update/delete/create data there as needed

Comment: I am also wondering since I haven't configured anything to do that. I believe I can delete old indices after seeing your comment.

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template`?

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you to decide number of indices. I suggest you should go through the document first. It should answer all your questions in great details :)
[Retire your data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/retiring-data.html)